# Répondre à « Bonjour »

Tags: expressions, salutations

On se retrouve souvent dans une situation où on devrait saluer quelqu'un qu'on est amené à fréquenter et qui nous a dit « Bonjour » ou « Comment ça va ! ».

Je me demande comment répondre de façon plus expressive que « Bonjour, oui ça va bien, merci ! » afin de développer la conversation et donner une bonne impression par la suite.

Sinon, le dialogue ci-dessous à beaucoup de chance de se répéter et cela devient banal donc **ennuyant**.

- Bonjour ça va ?
- Bonjour. Oui, ça va bien. Et toi ?

Comment: @Fólkvangr "Interpersonal skills" ne peut donner que des directives générales essentiellement fondées sur une façon de penser anglo-saxonne et non spécifique à un langage en particulier, sauf l'anglais. Ce qui intéresse le demandeur c'est l'usage en français dans le domaine de comment substituer des entrées en matière à la place de formules de politesse courantes. En cela on pourrait arguer qu'il s'agit d'une question sur la culture, seulement un grand nombre de question sur la culture française ont été acceptées et discutées sur le FSE.

Comment: La meilleure façon de développer la conversation après un "Bonjour, ça va?" est de répondre "Non".

Comment: @Fólkvangr If you want to be very polite, I think that you should add a merci to your answer. "Ca va bien. Merci. Et toi/vous ?"

Comment: Le problème que dans la pyscologie de l'interlocuteur 'Merci' signifièq je ne pas continuer la conversation /j'ai terminé la conversation

Answer (score 1):

Croire qu'il existerait beaucoup de formules figées dans ce domaine, des formules qui permettraient une variété intéressante et utilisable à volonté, c'est se leurrer. Il existe des schémas généraux de réplique pour des situations courantes et on peut donc leur apporter notre individualité en les utilisant ou on peut ne pas les utiliser du tout, mais toutes les formes de réplique, soit selon un modèle soit entièrement personnelles, doivent être fondées sur la vie même, sur les particularités de l'existence que nous partageons avec les personnes rencontrées. Chaque nouvelle rencontre d'une même personne peut aussi être sur la base de toujours le même contexte de gens qui n'ont rien à se dire et il n'y a aucun moyen de pallier à cette épouvantable monotonie que nous ressentons tous et il faut en prendre notre  partie, l'accepter. Cela entraine dans certaines circonstances un arrêt des échanges de politesse.
Mon avis est que l'on ne doit pas chercher à faire bonne impression ; il vaut mieux faire moins bonne impression que de donner une impression de ne pas être sincère, d'en remettre, de chercher à s'attirer les faveurs de quelqu'un. Tout cela ne veut pas dire qu'il faille réprimer ses vrais sentiments et si l'on éprouve des sentiments particuliers on peut essayer de les exprimer ; le tout est de le faire naturellement, adroitement, sans paraitre gauche et cela est un autre problème que seule une longue habitude du langage pourra résoudre. Les possibilité suivantes ne sont que des exemples, les variations à l'infini dépendent de l'utilisation que vous pouvez faire des circonstances.

1/ Vous n'avez pas vu cette connaissance depuis longtemps et vous vous sentez très heureux de la rencontrer de nouveau, ce qui se passe tout à fait par hasard dans une soirée;

- Ah  ! Mademoiselle X ! Je n'aurais pas espéré vous rencontrer ici, quel plaisir de vous revoir !

2/ Votre ami revient de vacances et il vous semble être en pleine forme, il a perdu le poids dont il se plaignait ; cela vous fait plaisir et vous souhaitez l'exprimer ;

- Eh bien ! Les vacances t'ont vraiment profité ! Tu t'es mis au sport pour retrouver une ligne comme ça ?

3/ Votre ami, Paul, est quelqu'un que vous rencontrez souvent, et  la présente rencontre n'a rien de spécial, mais ce jour-là vous êtes assez curieux de ce qu'il aurait à dire en général, à propos de sa vie ou d'autres choses ; la formule utilisée dans le présent cas est une formule toute faite et  on ne peut donc pas en abuser ; utilisée de temps en temps, en particulier lorsqu'on est motivé par une curiosité réelle, elle sert à rompre avec la monotonie. (N'allez surtout pas serrer la main à cinq de vos amis les uns après les autres dans un groupe en disant « Quoi de neuf ? » à chacun.)

- Paul ! Quoi de neuf ?

4/ Monsieur Z est votre supérieur hiérarchique au bureau et il vous rencontre au cinéma ; vous ne voulez pas paraitre trop distant en ne répliquant qu'avec un simple bonjour ;

- Monsieur Z ! Amateur de cinéma, je vois…

5/ Mademoiselle Y revient de vacances et vous la voyez pour la première fois quand elle retourne au bureau ;

- Comment ont été ces vacances ? Du beau temps ?

6/ Vous rencontrez un collègue  à la mairie et il est en train de faire des démarches, possiblement les mêmes que les vôtres ;

- Bonjour Jean, qu'est-ce qui t'amène ici, il te faut une nouvelle carte d'identité ?

---

Addition en réponse à une demande de user **famas22**
*Entre amis, est-ce qu'il y a une expression autre que « bonjour comment cava tranquille !? »*

*Réponse*

« bonjour comment cava tranquille !? » n'est pas de la langue standard. Il faut écrire « "Bonjour comment ça va tranquille ? », et ça n'est toujours pas du langage correct mais de la langue plutôt argotique ; ensuite, la tranquillité n'est pas un critère pertinent dans le contexte des choses importantes dans le déroulement de la vie (On n'est pas tranquille du tout, on est en pleines fêtes, il y a des gens à recevoir, à visiter, du bruit, de l'agitation, mais ça va très bien, on aime ça !). Vous pouvez dire toutes sortes de choses entre amis, il s'agit d'y penser. Si vous voulez seulement quelques formules simples et toutes faites que vous pouvez répéter il y a les suivantes.

- Bonjour, tu vas bien ?
- Bonjour, comment ça va ?
- Alors ? Comment va ? Bonjour ! ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Comment+va+%3F&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CComment%20va%20%3F%3B%2Cc0))
- Bonjour, tout va bien ?
- Bonjour, tout se passe bien pour toi ?
- Bonjour, ça va chez toi ? (*déplacement de l'intérêt pour la personne elle-même vers l'intérêt pour la personne dans le cadre du déroulement de sa vie familiale*)

Comment: Entre amis, est-ce qu'il y a une expression autre que "bonjour comment cava tranquille !?"

Comment: @famas22 J'ai ajouté des détails dans la réponse.